# Creating Sections for Post Types

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, templates

I'm trying to create this page structure within WordPress:

```
- Home                (http://example.com/)
- Blog                (http://example.com/blog/)
  - Blog Post         (http://example.com/blog/blog-post-name/)
- Projects            (http://example.com/projects/)
  - Projects Post     (http://example.com/projects/project-post-name/)
```

Following the WordPress Codex guide [Making Your Blog Appear in a Non-Root Folder](http://codex.wordpress.org/Making_Your_Blog_Appear_in_a_Non-Root_Folder) I'm able to create this structure:

```
- Home                (http://example.com/)
- Blog                (http://example.com/blog/)
  - Blog Post         (http://example.com/blog/blog-post-name/)
```

But not the "Projects" section. The Codex documents how to move where your blog  sits, but not handle different post types in this way.

I'm trying to achieve "Blog" page as the index of all "Blog Post" posts, and "Projects" page the index of all "Project Post" posts.

Comment: How do you register the post type? Please add that code to your question.

Comment: I haven't set up my post types yet, since I assumed the best way to do it would be based on the way these pages were set up. Any recommendations on that would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Set your regular permalinks to

```
/blog/%postname%/
```

Register your custom post type with `has_archive => TRUE` and `with_front => FALSE`.

Example:

```
add_action ( 'init', 'register_project_cpt' );

function register_project_cpt()
{
    register_post_type(
        'projects',
        array (
            'has_archive'          => TRUE,
            'hierarchical'         => TRUE,
            'public'               => TRUE,
            'publicly_queryable'   => TRUE,
            'rewrite'              => array (
                'slug'       => _x( 'projects', 'slug', 'text_domain' ),
                'with_front' => FALSE
            ),
            'show_in_nav_menus'    => TRUE,
            'show_in_menu'         => TRUE,
            'show_in_admin_bar'    => TRUE,
            'show_ui'              => TRUE,
            'supports'             => array(
                'author',
                'comments',
                'editor',
                'excerpt',
                'page-attributes',
                'revisions',
                'thumbnail',
                'title',
            )
        )
    );
}
```

In `wp-admin/options-reading.php` choose a page for the blog post archives, that will be used on `/blog/` then.

> [image]

Comment: Thanks for that. I've set the permalinks "Custom Structure" to `/blog/%postname%/` and set the reading settings to `Front page: Home` and `Posts page: Blog`, however the "Project" post type isn't showing up in the Admin Panel after pasting your provided code in to `functions.php`